# python subprocess.calledProcessError

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to use the python subprocess class to call a series of commands sequentially that will create a openCV virtualenv and then call my python script (that needs to be run within the cv virtualenv)

My code so far(with the help of a lot of people from stackoverflow) is this :

```
import sys
import os
from subprocess import check_call, STDOUT

DEVNULL = open(os.devnull,'r+b',0)

with open('log', 'wb', 0) as file:
check_call("""set -e -x
{python} -mpip install --user virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source ~/.bashrc
mkvirtualenv cv
cd /home/douglas/Desktop/TestePython/Assets
{python} novo.py
""".format(python=sys.executable),shell=True,
     executable='/bin/bash',stdin=DEVNULL,
     stdout=file, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
```

Which gives me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "programa.py", line 20, in <module>
stdout=file, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'set -e -x
/usr/bin/python -mpip install --user virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source ~/.bashrc
mkvirtualenv cv
cd /home/douglas/Desktop/TestePython/Assets
/usr/bin/python novo.py
' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

While in the log I get

```
/bin/bash: line 4: /home/douglas/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: 
No such file or directory
```

But the file exists.

The main goal is to execute all the commands like it would in a terminal, sequence is really important

Comment: note: `pip install --user` should put `virtualenvwrapper.sh` into `~/.local/bin/` directory, not `./usr/local/bin/` (btw, is the leading dot intentional?)

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, sorry about the dot, was a typo when i copied the code in here, 
i changed ./usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh to  ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh and it returns an similar error like this :
/bin/bash: line 4: /home/douglas/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: What happens if save the commands into a file and run it on the command line?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian, it returns ./test.sh: source: not found, but i dont know if i am using the .sh file properly, really don't have much knowledge about that

Comment: You should make the shell script work in the shell first, to separate the issues in the shell commands and the issues with how they are run in Python.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, much apreciated !